# Metric variation of a four-vector

Tags: general-relativity, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I am trying to calculate the metric variation $\frac{\delta T^{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$. Here, $T^{\alpha\beta}$ is the stress-energy tensor of a perfect fluid, given by $T^{\alpha\beta} = (\rho+p)u^\alpha u^\beta + g^{\alpha \beta} p$.

What I would get is therefore $$\frac{\delta T^{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} = \frac{\delta[(\rho+p)u^\alpha u^\beta]}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} +\frac{\delta g^{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} p.$$

What I do not understand is how to compute the term $\frac{\delta[(\rho+p)u^\alpha u^\beta]}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$. Is it null?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail on how you got to this calculation? While this might initially seem superfluous, knowing a bit more about the context might help us understand what you are trying to do and what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi @NíckolasAlves, for sure. I am trying to vary action (2.4) in [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1475-7516/2011/11/007). This particular action stems out from a coupling between standard matter and a certain scalar field. Specifically, such action depends on the stress-energy tensor of matter, which is contracted to derivatives of the scalar field. Hence when varying it I get the term that I have shown in my question.